# Custom page or action on "XML Parsing Error"

Tags: html, xhtml

## Question

Is there any possibility to tell browser via `HTTP header` or `html` code what to do when `XML Parsing Error` occurs? Like maybe `X-OnXmlParsingError`, `<meta name="onXmlParsingError" href="http://example.com"/>` etc.

## Additional info

Some more info: I generate `XHTML` code send to browser with `application/xhtml+xml` header. So, when something is wrong with my `xhtml` code, the browser instead of my beautiful webpage shows `XML Parsing Error` - and **that is expected behavior. But I want to change it**, and tell every browser what to do, when this error occurs. For example redirect to custom page that is well-malformed-for-sure with some friendly message.

I know I can parse the output code on server side, but I don't want this. It's highly inefficient and probability of unwell malformed code is... almost 0, but still.

## Browsers

### Opera

[hides the problem](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2011/09/28/no-more-xml-parsing-failed-errors):

> (...) we've decided to stop throwing draconian XML parsing failed error messages, and instead, attempt to reparse the document automatically as HTML. Instead of showing an error message in the browser, it's now dumped to the console, so as a developer, you can still find XML parsing error warnings in Opera Dragonfly and the Error Console if you want to.

### Firefox

generates

```
<parserror>(...)</parseerror>
```

instead of normal `html`, so it's easy to detect the error by `document.documentElement === 'html'`.

## Server-side workaround

Besides the question requirements, the fastest (2500 checks in 1 sec, T4200 @ 2.00Ghz) `PHP` validator I found is:

```
<?php
// returns 1 on success and 0 on failure
xml_parse(xml_parser_create(), $stringWithHtmlCode) == 1
```

---

I strongly recommend to read the comments under the accepted answer.

Comment: Interesting idea. But I don't believe there is anything you can do client side here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not retrieve the XHTML via an XMLHttpRequest (or early IE fallback), and check your ability to request xmlhttp.resposeXML.  If doing so throws an exception or returns null, redirect to your error page.  Otherwise, rewrite the document using window.onload = function() { document.write(xmlhttp.responseText); };

Comment: This is a very good solution, for at least once properly loaded page. What if the broken code is a part of response of a very first request? Anyway, thanks to you I can use my server-side workaround only for non-ajax requests.

Comment: Could your response to non-ajax requests be a minimalist static page that simply appends a special field onto the URL and then uses that to make an ajax request for the real page? That would seem to take care of the "very first request" issue.

Comment: Sounds good as well, but how to recognize within this first request if user has JavaScript turned on? Persuading user to click the special link in `<noscript>` is the only solution I have right now. Any other?

Comment: You can actually put `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=noscript.html">` within the `<noscript>` section, and it will be ignored if javascript is enabled... but then it's really not a static page since noscript.html needs to be replaced by the actual request plus yet another field.

Comment: OUTSTANDING. I completely forgot about this meta. And now, I hope the last question, what about Google? How they treat such approach? Will Google index crawler know how to cache all the website using all your suggestions?

Comment: Ha! Good point. I suppose you could look at the User-Agent in the HTTP request, and if it contains "bot", return the XHTML.  According to [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#User_agent_identification), web crawlers typically include "bot" in their User-Agent field.